# Echo value of product custom attribute - WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, attributes, echo

I need help with WordPress Woocommerce.

How could I echo the values of product custom attribute?

Problem: attribute values is printed all of them in one line.
I need to print out only 1 value on each  line

This is my code.

```
global $product;

if ( ! $product->is_purchasable() ) {
  return;
}
$custom_attr_values = array_shift( wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'first-attribute-name', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) ) );
?>

<div class="selection">
  <font color="white">First Attribute Name</font>
  <select>
    <option value=""><?php
      $subheadingvalues = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_first-attribute-name');
 foreach ( $subheadingvalues as $subheadingvalue ) {
        echo $subheadingvalue->name;
      }
      ?></option>
    <option value=""><?php
      $subheadingvalues = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_first-attribute-name');

      foreach ( $subheadingvalues as $subheadingvalue ) {
        echo $subheadingvalue->name;
      }
      ?></option>
    <option value=""><?php
      $subheadingvalues = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_first-attribute-name');

      foreach ( $subheadingvalues as $subheadingvalue ) {
        echo $subheadingvalue->name;
      }
      ?></option>
    <option value=""><?php
      $subheadingvalues = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_first-attribute-name');

      foreach ( $subheadingvalues as $subheadingvalue ) {
        echo $subheadingvalue->name;
      }
      ?></option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_terms() function to get the list of dropdown values http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

If you pass in the custom attribute name, you will get back a list of terms in that taxonomy.

or

```
global $product;
$custom_attr_values = array_shift( wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'custom_attr_name', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) ) );
```